# React: React-bootstrap modal not working in ie 10

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, internet-explorer-10, react-bootstrap

Using React-Bootstrap, I have a modal that conditionally opens. The modal works fine in ie 11.

Here is the modal that works in ie11..

```
handleCloseAlert() {
  this.setState({ alertShow: false });
}

handleShowAlert() {
  this.setState({ alertShow: true });
}
noResults() {
  this.setState({alertShow:true})
}

<Modal show={this.state.alertShow} 
          onHide={this.handleCloseAlert}
          {...this.props}
          data-toggle="modal"
          size="sm"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Body>No results found</Modal.Body>
          </Modal.Header>
        </Modal>
```

When I test in ie10 the screen goes white when the modal is supposed to open.
Here is the error I get in console..

```
[object Error]{description: "Unable to s...", message: "Unable to s...", name: "TypeError", number: -2146823281, stack:
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to set property 'paddingRight' of undefined or null reference
```

I also tested using just Bootstrap code and the modal works with the example code from bootstrap's website. I suppose I could use their code, but I couldnt firgure out how to conditionally open and close the modal.

Here is the example from bootstrap that is not coded for conditional react rendering..

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding `show={this.state.alertShow}` to the modal tag, but I get this error in the console.

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `show`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: show="false" or show={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with show={condition && value}, pass show={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

Is there a way to keep my current code and get it to work with ie10? Or do I need to recode without React-Bootstrap?

I also have `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';` in my index.js

Comment: This isn’t meant to be sarcastic, but support for IE10 has ended years ago and are virtually no users using that version based on usage statistics. Are you absolutely certain you need to support IE10 with your application?

Comment: unfortunately yes.

Comment: I'd like to know have you set the paddingRight property in your code? If so, what is the value?

Comment: That's the strange part. The only paddingRight that is defined is nested in the node modules for the modal in react-bootstrap. I tried commenting it out, but it had no effect.

Comment: Update. Supposedly react-bootstrap is supposed to work with IE 10. And everything is, except the modal. Is it possible I have my polyfill setup wrong. I am using react-app-polyfill package. Is that enough or do I also need a cdn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal is working with the new react-bootstrap update